# How to print individual elements of a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, output, io-monad

I am a beginner in Haskell and I wanted to know if it was possible to print individual elements of a given list. I tried solving this problem but have failed. This is the code:

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    let list = [1,2,3]
    let size = length list
    let temp = print_elem list size
    print temp


print_elem :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
print_elem xs x = do
    let size = length xs
    let idx = size - x
    let element = xs !! idx
    putStr (show element)
    putStr(" ")
    let dummy = print_elem (xs (x-1))
    return " "
```

I wanted to print something like this

```
1 2 3
```

If I simply use `putStr (show list)` it will display `[1,2,3]` and I don't want that.

But when I run this code multiple errors occur

```
printelem.hs:14:5: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `IO b0'
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStr (show element)
      In the expression:
        do let size = length xs
           let idx = size - x
           let element = xs !! idx
           putStr (show element)
           ....
      In an equation for `print_elem':
          print_elem xs x
            = do let size = ...
                 let idx = ...
                 let element = ...
                 ....
   |
14 |     putStr (show element)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

printelem.hs:16:29: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Int -> [Int]'
                  with actual type `[Int]'
    * The function `xs' is applied to one argument,
      but its type `[Int]' has none
      In the first argument of `print_elem', namely `(xs (x - 1))'
      In the expression: print_elem (xs (x - 1))
   |
16 |     let dummy = print_elem (xs (x-1))
   |                             ^^^^^^^^
```

How do you fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are thinking too imperatively. First, you need a list of strings, not a list of integers. That's `map`:

```
> map show [1,2,3]
["1","2","3"]
```

Next, you want to join them into a single, space-separate string. That's `Data.List.intercalate`:

```
> import Data.List
> intercalate " " (map show [1,2,3])
"1 2 3"
```

which you can then pass to `putStrLn` (`print` would give you the string representation of the string you already have):

```
import Data.List

main :: IO()
main = do
    let list = [1,2,3]
    putStrLn (intercalate " " (map show list))
```

Comment: What is the reason for using `map` and `show` on the list?

Comment: `intercalate` needs a list of strings (or more precisely, `intercalate x` need a list of values with the same type as `x`). `intercalate " " [1, 2, 3]` doesn't type check.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is

```
> mapM_ putStr (intersperse " " (map show [1,2,3])) >> putStrLn ""
1 2 3
it :: ()
```

This prints the elements one by one, converted to strings by `show`, interspersed with the spaces in between.

```
> intersperse " " (map show [1,2,3])
["1"," ","2"," ","3"]
it :: [[Char]]
```

`mapM_` maps an `IO` action constructor `putStr :: String -> IO ()` on each of the elements, and executes them all as one combined sequence of actions.

Finally this code prints the newline.